# Using fadeout animation thrice on a single textview while changing text after each animation

Tags: android

I am making an android app in which I want to use the animation:

1. A text "text1" appears at the center of the screen.
2. Then this texts fades away in 1 sec and then another text "text2" appears on the same place.
3. Then "text2" fades away in 1sec and finally another text "text3" appears on the same place and stays on the screen.

What I did was, created a TextView.

```
TextView textview;
textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
Animation r1;
r1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadeout);
textview.setText("text1");
textview.startAnimation(r1);
textview.setText("text2");
textview.startAnimation(r1);
textview.setText("text3");
```

But It doesn't work.

This is the fadeout anim I used :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
android:fromAlpha="1.0" 
android:toAlpha="0.0" 
android:duration="1000"
/>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29218173/android-text-fade-in-and-out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use AnimationListener for that purpose

```
Animation r1,r2,r3;
 r1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadeout);
 r2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadeout);
 r3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadeout);
textview.setText("text1");
textview.startAnimation(r1);

 r1.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){         
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation fade1)
            {

             textview.setText("text2");
             textview.startAnimation(r2);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
        });


r2.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){         
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation fade1)
            {
                 textview.setText("text3");
             textview.startAnimation(r3);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
        });
```

Comment: Yeahh this worked but Can we add a little pause of 200 ms between the three animation?

Comment: Yes call second and third animation after some delay using handler.postdelay . Google it.

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this

```
public class FadeOutInActivity extends Activity
{
 Handler mHandler;
 TextView mTextView;

Animation in;
Animation out;
int mTotalCount;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show);

    mTotalCount = 0;

    mHandler = new Handler();
    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    in = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
    in.setDuration(1000);

    out = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
    out.setDuration(1000);
    out.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            mTotalCount++;

            if (mTotalCount == 1) {
                mTextView.setText("text2");
            } else if (mTotalCount == 2)  {
                mTextView.setText("text3");
            }

            mTextView.startAnimation(in);
            mHandler.postDelayed(mFadeOut, 1000);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    //mSwitcher.startAnimation(out);
    mTextView.setText("text1");
    mTextView.startAnimation(in);
    mHandler.postDelayed(mFadeOut, 1000);

}

private Runnable mFadeOut =new Runnable(){

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Speed up the last fade-out so that the Activity opens faster

        out.setDuration(1000);

        mTextView.startAnimation(out);
    }
};
 }
```

and layout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Name"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```